# How to combine 2 fields from 2 tables into one field using Delphi SQL

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm trying to combine 2 fields from 2 tables into one field, not one record using **Delphi SQL**.

This is what my tables look like:

Table1:

```
   ItemID
   ------
   E001
   E002
   E004
   I001
```

Table2:

```
   ItemID
   ------
   E002
   E003
   I001
   I002
```

ItemID servers as a key between the two tables.  I am trying to write a query that will return the following:

```
   ItemID
   E001 
   E002
   E003 
   E004 
   I001
   I002
```

Is this possible and if so how? `JOIN` didn't seem to work and `UNION` didn't either unless there is something I must do in my actual database design. Any ideas as to what will work?

Comment: Can you post the actual queries you attempted?

Comment: You tagged it as mysql and sql-server. Please decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like what you want is the following query:

```sql
select ItemID
from Table1
union
select ItemID
from Table2
```

The `union` eliminates duplicate rows. If you want to keep the duplicate, use `union all`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach (assumed MySQL due to mysql tag):

```
   select ItemId as ItemId
   from Table1 as t1
   union 
   select ItemId  as ItemId
   from Table2 as t2
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a291/5)

If you really want to have `*` as a part of you result then please use following code (simulated left outer join):

```
 select IFNULL(t.ItemId1, t.ItemId2), case when t.ItemId1 = t.ItemId2 then '*' else '' end as star
 from(
  select t1.ItemId as ItemId1, t2.ItemId  as ItemId2 FROM Table1  t1
  left join Table2  t2 on t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId
  union
  select t1.ItemId as ItemId1, t2.ItemId as ItemId2  FROM Table1  t1
  right join Table2  t2 on t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId
) as t
```

[2ND DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a291/21)

Comment: Where's the `*` denoting value exists in both tables as OP requests?

Comment: He's using Delphi, not MySQL.  @xQbert OP was using that as a marker for columns that only existed in one table - I don't think he wanted them as part of the resultset.

Comment: @xQbert - isn't * just a marker? Or is it a part of result?

Comment: Guess the OP will have to answer that I took the combine in subject to mean he wanted the * as well, seemed off to me, but maybe you're right.  Additionally the "Not one record" made me think the * was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming delphi supports full outer joins...  Don't think mySQL does...

This takes the first non-null value from the resulting outer joins and uses it.  if the value is found in both tables a ' *' is concatenated to the end of the value, otherwise it is left alone.

```
SELECT concat(coalesce(T1.itemID, T2.itemID), 
       case when t1.itemID=t2.itemID then ' *' else '' end) as ItemID
FROM table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.ItemID = T2.ItemID
```

if not we could use the poor mans outer join...  left join on t1-->t2 then union T2-->t1  something like...

```
SELECT concat(coalesce(T1.itemID, T2.itemID), 
       case when t1.itemID=t2.itemID then ' *' else '' end) as ItemID
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.ItemID = T2.ItemID

UNION 

SELECT concat(coalesce(T1.itemID, T2.itemID), 
       case when t1.itemID=t2.itemID then ' *' else '' end) as ItemID
FROM table2 T2
LEFT JOIN table1 T1
 on T1.ItemID = T2.ItemID
```

Comment: I don't  think OP actually wanted to concatenate the `*` to the resultset.  If I understood correctly, he was using those to mark values that were not present in both tables.